# How to delete only the table relationed

Tags: sql, laravel, migration

I know how to create the migrations with laravel 5.1 and I have the following code

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('articulos', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('content');
            $table->integer('categoria_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('creador_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('slug', 32);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
        Schema::table('articulos', function($table) {
            $table->foreign('categoria_id')->references('id')->on('categorias');
            $table->foreign('creador_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        });
    }
```

When I try to delete a category with articles , I have an error with foreign key , it's anny possibility to drop this category ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating a foreign key constraint, you can also decide what should happen with the constraints. For instance, if you want to delete all articles when a category is deleted (as I guess is your question):

```
    Schema::table('articulos', function($table) {
        $table->foreign('categoria_id')->references('id')->on('categorias')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('creador_id')->references('id')->on('users');
    });
```

Also see [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/migrations#foreign-key-constraints). The `cascade` identifies to the database that `on deletion` of a `categorias` entry, the table should `cascade` the action into the `articulos` table.

To further clarify the options in this foreign constraint, you can use:

- `onDelete('set null')` to make the column value null once the foreign key is deleted
- `onDelete('restrict')` (default behavior) denies deletion of foreign key if still entries exist
- `onDelete('cascade')` to automatically delete entries once the foreign key is deleted

More information for [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html). Please note that foreign key constraint are not necessary for Laravel to support relations. Sometimes you might not need a foreign key.

Also note aside from the `onDelete` you can also use `onUpdate`.

Comment: Thanks for the answers , I need this options !! :D